# Reset participation cookie

Tags: limesurvey

In LimeSurvey you can choose to use cookies to forbid double participation. How can I reset the cookies on the survey side (i.e. tell it to use a different seed or whatever). Because I've launched a survey for a small number of people as a test drive, but now I want to launch it for real, and as I've made changes to it I want to allow people to participate.

Comment: Copy your survey, activate it , and delete another one ( the first).

Comment: @DenisChenu I've figured out that one myself. But this is a bit painful considering that your mages may be broken and so on…

Comment: Images : Use included export/import survey resources. The cookie LimeSurvey system do what you ask, i don't see any problem. Better is to unset this when testing.